# How do I solve this in an understandable and direct way?

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-explanation, real-numbers

For each $i \in \Bbb N$, let $f_i: \Bbb N \mapsto \{0, 1\}$.

Let $A = \{f_i : i \in \Bbb N\}$ and $E = \{n \in \Bbb N : f_n(n) = 0\}$.

Does there exist a $f \in A$ such that $E = \{n \in\Bbb N : f(n) = 1\}$

I think that there does not exist a $f \in A$ such that $E = \{n \in\Bbb N : f(n) = 1\}$. However, I am unsure on how to prove it. How do I show my answer in an understandable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Let $f=f_k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

If $k\in E$, where $E = \{n \in \Bbb N : f_n(n) = 0\}$, then $f_k(k) = 0$. Assume $E=E_2$, where $E_2 = \{n \in\Bbb N : f(n) = 1\}$. Then, $k\in E_2$ as well and $f_k(k)=1$, which contradicts the premise $f_k(k)=0$. It follows, $E\neq E_2$, which contradicts what we wanted to show.

If $k\notin E$, then $f_k(k)=1$. Assume $E=E_2$. Then, $k\notin E_2$ as well and $f_k(k)=0$, which contradicts the premise $f_k(k)=1$. It follows $E\neq E_2$, which contradicts what we wanted to show.